# Insert a string at a specific position in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query

```
SELECT email_text INTO  v_result 
    FROM  test.record_notification 
    WHERE record_notification_id = p_recordnotification_id;
```

which returns the below result

[br/] [br/] [br/]Record Id : Record Name : Title Id : Title Name[br/][ul]http://localhost:8080/myproject/ShowRecords.action?recordsVO.recordId=3324&recordId=3324&status =Record Requested >3324  : DEV: test contract : 2448730 : Titanic[/ul]

**However I want to add "[th]" "[/th]" in the result above so that the final string becomes**

[br/] [br/] [br/][th]Record Id : Record Name : Title Id : Title Name[br/][/th][th]http://localhost:8080/myproject/ShowRecords.action?recordsVO.recordId=3324&recordId=3324&status =Record Requested >3324  : DEV: test contract : 2448730 : Titanic[/th]

**please note that there can be multiple records like this .**

Please suggest a way in PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your query by

```
SELECT '[br/] [br/] [br/]<th>' || replace(replace(email_text,'[br/]',''),'ul','th') INTO  v_result 
    FROM  test.record_notification 
    WHERE record_notification_id = p_recordnotification_id;
```

I am assuming that you have a problem of one record only
thanks

**[Edit]**

If you are not worring about your ***br*** then just do

```
 SELECT '<th>' || replace(replace(email_text,'[br/]',''),'ul','th') INTO  v_result 
        FROM  test.record_notification 
        WHERE record_notification_id = p_recordnotification_id;
```

It will work in a 99% case

Comment: @ronan well,its for the multiple ones you need to make one function or something you wrong for the one only so i give you an answer.
it should be customize by your requirement

Comment: @just_code 
could you be show me how it can be done for multiple records ?

Comment: @ronan not sure as of now.Because you don't have fix input from user already i was afraid about multiple ones. you should analyze your inputs from user and then add `replace` functions or alternate ones for this.this could be your answer